# Simple C++ script - Factorial - Errors

Tags: c++, factorial

I am learning C++. Here is a code counting factorial(silnia). Liczba means number.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int _main() 
{
    int silnia;
    int n;
    if (n == 0) return 1;
    else;
    return n * silnia(n-1);

    int liczba;
    cout << "Podaj liczbe: ";
    cin >> liczba;
    cout << liczba << "! = " << silnia(liczba) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However I still become error message:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int _main()':
main.cpp:9:20: error: 'silnia' cannot be used as a function
 return n*silnia(n-1);
                    ^
main.cpp:14:42: error: 'silnia' cannot be used as a function
 cout << liczba << "! = " << silnia(liczba) << endl
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: The error message is very clear. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I don't think you need StackOverflow to answer that. Google should be more than enough to find a working example of what you are trying to achieve. Nice cat, by the way...

Comment: You're trying to use silnia as a function. Silnia is an integer variable. You probably want to write the code that calculates the silnia value inside of a function called silnia.

Comment: You are attempting something too advanced. Try something simpler and advance slowly.

Answer (score 1):

delete this part from your main:

```
 int silnia;
 int n;
 if (n == 0) return 1;
 else;
 return n * silnia(n-1);
```

put this function outside main function

```
 int silnia(int a)
{
 if(a==0) return 1;
 else return silnia(a-1)*a;
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks all for help! I made an analysis of this code, then similar app, everything works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

```
silnia(liczba)
```

Looks like you're trying to "call" the integer `silnia`.  Exactly what your error message says. I'm not sure what you're trying to do in that line.

Comment: So how it can be improved? I am at the beginning learning and searched internet for solution but somehow I still do not understand that error :(

Comment: @PawełGranat Do you know the correct way to create functions?